# Unity UI.Button not registering Pointer events

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-ui

I'm trying to learn Unity again and one of the many (seemingly easily) things I'm struggling with is trying to get my `ButtonEvents` script to fire when interacting with my Button UI component.

I'm trying to get my script to log to the console when either a `PointerEnter`, `PointerExit` or `PointerClick` event happens - but nothing gets logged to the `Console` when playing the scene.

I've noticed that if I placed this on a TextMeshPro canvas, the events work, but *not* when applied to by UI Button (created via `UI -> Button - TextMeshPro`)

This must be something simple that I'm missing not knowing about Unity Editor.

Thanks for any help!

---

Hierarchy (`EventSystem` component is included):

[image: heirarchy]

Inspector:

[image: Button in inspector]

Scene:

[image: Button UI in scene]

Here is my `ButtonEvents` script:

```cs
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

namespace UI
{
    public class ButtonEvents : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler, IPointerClickHandler
    {
        public static event Action<GameObject, PointerEventData> OnPointerEnterEvent;
        public static event Action<GameObject, PointerEventData> OnPointerClickEvent;
        public static event Action<GameObject> OnPointerExitEvent;

        public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
        {
            OnPointerEnterEvent?.Invoke(gameObject, pointerEventData);
            Debug.Log("OnPointerEnter");
        }

        public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
        {
            OnPointerExitEvent?.Invoke(gameObject);
            Debug.Log("OnPointerExit");
        }

        public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
        {
            OnPointerClickEvent?.Invoke(gameObject, pointerEventData);
            Debug.Log("OnPointerClick");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so after exhausting other options, I created a new version of the Button - the only thing different I can see is that the new `Button` uses the `Image` component and now everything works - the events all seem fine in the Unity Editor Console.

[image: working button]

Comment: `Image` has the `RaycastTarget` property.. I think in general you need at least one visual element to interact with or alternatively collider + then your camera needs  `PhysicsRaycaster` component ;)

Comment: Thanks @derHugo! All these things will throw me at first, but good to learn what I can and can't do.